# IE 7 compatibility mode position:absolute bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The #footerdetails div of my page is absolutely positioned and anchored to the bottom. (i know, IE problem iminent)

anyway... 
http://talga.sanscode.com/blog

Take a look at the footer in IE 7 (ie 8 compat). has a number all the way on the right hand side of the screen.

In every other browser it's on the left where it should be.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Jason

Comment: I guess this is fixed since I can't see an issue? I did notice however that you don't have the rss feed and links in IE7 on the right like you do with the other browser versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jason;

i saw it in IE may you have to define  `width` `like width:200px;` to your #footerdetails div because in IE7 it's take `width 100%` of the screen.

css

```
#footerdetails {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position:fixed;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IE 7 doesn't do `position:fixed`, can you not make it absolute to the sidebar?
Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebarmenu_container">
 <ul id="sidebarmenu"/>
 <div id="footerdetails"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebarmenu_container {
 position: relative;
}

#footerdetails {
 position: absolute;  //instead of position: fixed;
}
```